# SSIS - OLEDB Source - how to use sql query with variables?

Tags: sql, sql-server, ssis, etl

I have this query that I want to export its contents to a table:

```
DECLARE @bdname VARCHAR(50)
SET @bdname = ?

SELECT 
    @bdname, 
    CONVERT(CHAR(30), dp2.name), 
    CONVERT(CHAR(20), dp.name) 
FROM  
    sys.database_principals AS dp 
INNER JOIN
    sys.database_role_members AS drm ON dp.principal_id = drm.role_principal_id 
INNER JOIN
    sys.database_principals AS dp2 ON drm.member_principal_id = dp2.principal_id
WHERE  
    (dp2.principal_id > 4) AND (dp2.type <> 'R')
```

If I put this as part of a Execute SQL Task, it goes ok, but I can't (don't know how) then map the results into something that I can export to a SQL table.

Can anyone guide me on how can I put the results of this query into a table? It's because if I use dataflow and ole db source, it does not accept this type of query.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Add a `dataflow task`, inside it add an `Oledb source` and an `Oledb destination`.

Add a variable of type string , set `Evaluate as expression` to `true` and assign the following expression:

```
"SELECT '" + @[User::bdname] + "' , convert(char(30),dp2.name), convert(char(20),dp.name) 
FROM  sys.database_principals AS dp INNER JOIN
sys.database_role_members AS drm ON dp.principal_id = drm.role_principal_id 
INNER JoIN
sys.database_principals AS dp2 ON  drm.member_principal_id = dp2.principal_id
WHERE  (dp2.principal_id > 4) AND (dp2.type <> 'R')"
```

(Assuming bdname value is stored in `user::bdname` variable)

In the `Oledb source` set the source type to `Sql command from variable` and choose the created variable

Map the `oledb source` to the `oledb destination`

**UPDATE 1**

After reading your comment *"...This foreach loop will query the sys.databases for all the user databases, and it is supposed to iterate that variable, to get the permissions"*.

To iterate over databases you have to add an `Execute SQL Task` with an SQL Command

```
SELECT name from sys.databases
```

and set the Result Set to `Full Result Set` , and assign the Result Set to a variable of type `Object`

Link this Execute SQL Task to the `ForEach Loop Container`

In the foreach Loop Container change the enumerator type to `Ado enumerator` and choose the object variable as source

[image][image]

Also don't forget to set the Dataflow task `Delay Validation` property to `True`

**UPDATE 2 (workaround)**

Try joining your query with `sys.databases` instead of using `Foreach loop container` *(i don't know if it achieve what you want to do)*

```
SELECT db.name, convert(char(30),dp2.name), convert(char(20),dp.name) 
FROM  sys.database_principals AS dp INNER JOIN
sys.database_role_members AS drm ON dp.principal_id = drm.role_principal_id 
INNER JoIN
sys.database_principals AS dp2 ON drm.member_principal_id = dp2.principal_id
INNER JOIN sys.databases as db ON db.owner_sid = dp2.sid
WHERE  (dp2.principal_id > 4) AND (dp2.type <> 'R')
```

Comment: It doesn't accept that I use the variables in the begining... Already did that :/

Comment: @Filburt, how do I do that? I followed a tutorial, actually, to try using from variable, but it didn't work. Maybe I did it wrong. Thanks!

Comment: Trying to implement it. I'm gonna have to convert that var to user:bdname, but when I try to do it, it says it is not supported. Maybe because it is an object, because that var contains a list of databases

Comment: Didn't understand that, you was using `declare @bdname varchar(50)` how it could be of type object?

Comment: Ok, Hadi, I've managed to use the solution you provided, but not fully. still don't know exactly am I going to assign the multiple values of the databse names to that variable, because this piece of code is part of a Foreach Loop container. This foreach loop will query the sys.databases for all the user databases, and it is supposed to iterate that variable, to get the permissions.

Comment: @NunoSilva If I may chip in again: I usually pipeline the query result in to an `RecordSet` (that is bound to a variable) and `ForEach` over the `RecordSet`. In any case, designing a query that makes the loop obsolete is preferable for your specific task.

Comment: Sorry, and thanks Hadi. Actually last night I had made it following the tips you had given.